# How to correctly deal with failed or cancelled IAP content downloads?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am working through the non-consumable Apple-hosted IAP examples in Ray Wenderlich's iOS 6 by tutorials book. There he suggests that the code calls `finishTransaction:` even when the download fails or is cancelled. But shouldn't I leave the transaction unfinished until the content is 100% available to the user?

Also how do I deal with a failed download? How can I restart it manually?